# Sorting Nested Lists with Various Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have a nested list like:

```
[["bla","blabla","x=17"],["bla","x=13","z=13","blabla"],["x=27","blabla","bla","y=24"]]
```

I need to have this sorted by x (from least to most) as (other strings should stay where they are):

```
[["bla","x=13","z=13","blabla"],["bla","blabla","x=17"],["x=27","blabla","bla","y=24"]]
```

and also from most to least:

```
[["x=27","blabla","bla","y=24"],["bla","blabla","x=17"],["bla","x=13","z=13","blabla"]]
```

I think I have to use key=lambda but I just couldn't figure out how to do it. Searched through the web and this website but I just can't do it.

Comment: Start by writing a function which extracts the value of x from one sublist. If you're not sure how to do that, try just getting the string starting with x, e.g. it should return "x=17".

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it, here's one with a lambda function:

```
mylist = [["bla","blabla","x=17"],["bla","x=13","z=13","blabla"],["x=27","blabla","bla","y=24"]]

mylist.sort(key = lambda l:int([item for item in l if 'x=' in item][0].split('=')[1]), reverse = True)

# [['x=27', 'blabla', 'bla', 'y=24'],
#  ['bla', 'blabla', 'x=17'],
#  ['bla', 'x=13', 'z=13', 'blabla']]
```